# printf like behaviour?

Tags: c, macos

I have a function as below

```
extern "C" int FuncTrace(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    return printf(fmt, args);
}
```

If I print some thing on console as below, it does not work?

```
FuncTrace(" %s  \n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
```

Can someone help me correct the FuncTrace() ?

Comment: Please include the error message next time :)

Comment: It just did not print anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [`vprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/vprintf.html) function if you want to pass in a `va_list` pseudo-argument:

```
return vprintf(fmt, args);
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that `printf()` accepts a `va_list` as its first argument. It does not, it wants a string. You need to use `vprintf()`:

```
return vprintf(fmt, args);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to use `vprintf` in your `FuncTrace` function instead of `printf`?